# pd.read_json error when using in aws

Tags: python, json, pandas, amazon-web-services, valueerror

I'm a newbie to aws and json files. I'm trying to read a json file in a instance in aws with the code: pd.read_json('train.json') but I receive the ValueError message:

ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)

The json file is downloaded from kaggle competetion: https://www.kaggle.com/c/statoil-iceberg-classifier-challenge/data. There are two columns are image data with some of the number like this "-27.878360999999998"

I didn't received any error message when I run it in my local computer. In the aws instance (Deep Learning AMI -Amazon Linux--2-0), I tried using the absolute path, but it dosen't work. One thing is that, I can read other json files use the same line of code in that instance. Just can't read this json file with long numbers.

this is how the data looks like, I get the dataframe in my local computer.

['train.json' to dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5OZM.png)

The python, pandas in the server are the same or newer version than my local computer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and the workaround I found was:

1. Use any unzip tool to extract the json.7z file.
2. There will be files extracted here: 'processed/data/train.json'. 
   This file worked when opened using pandas on my AWS AMI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me as well! And it's much faster to upload a zip file instead of the json file.Thank you so much.